# Nativescript couchbase plugin Basic Authentication

Tags: authentication, nativescript, couchbase-lite, angular2-nativescript

What is the recommended way of setting up basic authentication in nativescript project with couchbase as backend.

Currently im using nativescript and couchbase lite plugin.

Mike

Comment: No, sorry, that's off topic: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic*

Comment: you could find an example, how to use `nativescript-couchbase` in this repo- https://github.com/couchbaselabs/nativescript-couchbase  In regard to that you could also review the given demo in the plugin repo.

Comment: Authentication has not yet been added to the plugin.  Since it is a community driven project things move a bit slower.  Please open a ticket for that feature.

Comment: If I don't use the plugin, and just make rest calls, what would be the proper procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Although Couchbase Server offers a full featured REST api and SDKs for different languages/platforms, the mobile device is not meant to communicate with Couchbase Server directly (ports 8091-9000), but rather through Sync Gateway (port 4984), which is an abstraction layer above Couchbase Server running simplified set of operations.

Couchbase Lite is mostly a local database, which only communicates with Sync Gateway during replication operations. Replications synchronize local to remote database (push) or remote to local database (pull). Currently, replications use web-socket (ws) instead of http. That's when username/password are needed. Examples are [here](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-couchbase-plugin).

But Sync Gateway also exposes a full set of operations through a [REST API](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/2.6/rest-api.html), which you can consume without the Couchbase Lite Plugin. And there you can open a session instead of sending user/password in every call.